# Looking for a fantasy short story/novel - an adventuring party explores a dungeon, dies one by one, and the one survivor becomes a dungeon master

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, novel

In the early 2000s, I read a fantasy short story. I'm 90% sure it was a short story but it honestly could be a novel. It was in French (I live in France) but I can't remember if it was translated from another language.

The story was about a typical adventuring party exploring a dungeon. The main character was a human, but there was also an elf woman and maybe a dwarf. Most of the party ends up dying one by one to monsters or traps, and the human is the only survivor. He is so traumatized by the experience that he chooses to become the master of this dungeon.

This is pretty weird and honestly might not help but I also remember something about an insectoid-looking armor in the story. Maybe the hero puts it on at the end? I'm honestly not too sure about that, maybe I'm mixing it up with another story.
I think also I recall one of the party members getting eaten by a monster?

I keep thinking about this story and would love to read it again, but my memories are too vague to find it on Google.

Would love you guys' help on this one!

Comment: Nicely detailed first question, welcome to SF&F! If you're struggling to think of details to add, take a look at this [helpful checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337), hopefully it will spark a memory or two